# Drupal 7 - Why does $acc->value()->name print out the username?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

```
<?php
$involved_users = array();
//grab usernames from user reference field of a node
$project = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
// field_users is user reference field
foreach ($project->field_users as $acc) {
  $involved_users[] = $acc->value()->name;
}

var_dump($involved_users);
?>
```

Hi Guys,

I got this bit of code from http://pixeljets.com/blog/writing-robust-code-uses-fields-drupal-7

I have been going through it but I can't seem to figure out how "$acc->value()->name;" work?

What is value()? Is it PHP method or a Drupal one. I can't find any documentation on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the blog post you provided carefully, you'll see that the `value()` method is provided by `entity_metadata_wrapper()` from the [Entity](http://drupal.org/project/entity) module.

Comment: Thanks you! I must have missed it.